# Shadow catcher layer for After Effects not rendering

Tags: rendering

I am rendering out a CGI sequence for use in After Effects using this process https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_B2H_jnaoU

I have done this several times before and it has worked wonderfully, but for some odd reason, for this scene, the shadow catcher layer doesn't render. All of my settings on the render layers are the same as the video's

[image]

[image]

What else could be interfering?

Comment: can you upload your file?

Comment: is your light source in both layers?

Answer (score 1):

You should have both Scene Layers 1 and 3 selected so both layers affect each other. Your render layers can stay as is.

[image]

Also, you are using Layer 3 to mask out Layer 1, but because Layer 3 contains objects in front and behind the character on Layer 1 it's masking out the character completely.

You'll probably need to need put the elements behind the character (floor, etc.) on a different layer.

[image]

[image]

I'm getting something like this for the Shadows>Shadow pass.

[image]

Also, I noticed you're rendering out to PNG file without using the compositor. Doing it this way will just give you your main Combined pass. You'll need to render to a MultiLayer EXR (renders all passes into one file per frame), OR you'll have to set up File Output nodes in the compositor to render out separate PNG image sequences for the additional render passes you need.

Comment: Checking the scene layers did not work. Here is  a shared Dropbox folder if you guys want to mess around with it. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/odxelpmfzgk99sx/AABohR1f_v3vChj8wlUiYrjya?dl=0 (it was too big to share the normal way)

Comment: I've added the shadow pass that I'm getting, perhaps you could indicate what shadows are not showing up that you're trying to get?

Comment: Those are the shadows I'm looking for! But I've done what you've suggested and all I'm getting its the checkers blender shows before an image is rendered. Is there any thing else you did?